# How to make a subscope in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, scope, scoping

In C I can insert pairs of brackets to indicate a subscope.

```
int main() {
    int x = 5;
    {
        int y = 6;
        x += y; //Works
    }
    x = y+8; //Uh oh
}
```

In Swift, if I try something similar it will assume I'm trying to call the previous statement as a function, or errors for other reasons. How do I simply make a subscope in Swift, to deallocate variables earlier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
do {   
     // insert sub scope code
}
```